# Makes pointer from integer without a cast warning in singleton int

Tags: objective-c, class, singleton, integer, warnings

Objective-C, xCode for iOS

In a class, I want to assign a singleton integer's value. Right now I have:

[ExGlobal sharedMySingleton].tetraCountEx = tetraCount;

I've got this warning before, and have been able to resolve it, but this seems like I would have to do something different by letting the compiler know that tetraCountEx is an integer. I just don't know how.

Comment: Can you add how you declared `tetraCountEx` in `EXGlobal`?

Comment: is tetraCountEx (nonatomic, assign)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is a result of trying to store a number as a pointer. With out you posting any code as to how `tetraCountEX` is declared I can only guess what your problem is.

On reason may be that `tetraCountEx` is defined as an `NSNumber` and if that is the case use

```
[ExGlobal sharedMySingleton].tetraCountEx = [NSNumber numberWithInt:tetraCount];
//or numberWithInteger: or the appropriate type
```

And the other reason may be accidentally declaring tetraCountEx as a pointer

```
//Remove the * if this is the case
@property(nonatomic, assign) int *tetraCountEx;
```

Comment: Thank you.. it was because I had a * on the property!